# React - what is wrong with my custom hook for click outside of element?

Tags: reactjs

I have a custom hook for click outside of element in a menu. What happens is: when i click on "open menu", it opens menu, when i click outside it closes it (all good) but when I click again on the button "open menu" to close it (after opening it), it closes it for a second and then opens it again. I have been looking trying ti find the reason but cant. any help would be great. Sorry if i didnt phrase my question well, i did not know how to ask more clear :) Thank you!!

```
const { useState, useRef } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = React.useState(false)

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="menu-section-conatainer">
        <button
          className={"menu-link"}
          onClick={() => {
            setShowMenu(true)
          }}
          name={title}
        >
          open menu
        </button>
      </div>

      <Menu
        showState={showMenu}
        clickHandler={setShowMenu}
      >
        {children}
      </Menu>
    </div>
  )
}

const Menu = ({ children, clickHandler, showState}) => {
  const ref = useRef()
  useOnClickOutside(ref, () => clickHandler(false))

  return (
    <div
      className="menu-expanded-wrapper"
    >
      <div ref={ref} className="menu-expanded">
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

const useOnClickOutside = (ref, handler) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const listener = event => {
      if (!ref.current || ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
        return
      }
      handler(event)
    }

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", listener)
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", listener)

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", listener)
      document.removeEventListener("touchstart", listener)
    }
  }, [ref, handler])
}
```

Comment: So you're calling `useOnClickOutside` with the reference to the menu and a reference to this function `() => clickHandler(false)`. In other words whenever `handler` is called inside  `useOnClickOutside` it hides the menu. I don't know if I get the logic there to be honest. Can you load the basic version into CodeSandbox? Here, I started it for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-zhukovsky-epwp4?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your menu component closes then opens again immediately when clicking the button while the menu is already open is that when you click the button, the listener in `useOnClickOutside` is called (and closes the menu) then the `onClick` function on the button is called (and opens the menu).

You can fix this by moving the use of `useOnClickOutside` to the `App` component and placing the ref on an element that's a parent of both the button and the menu so that clicks on the button are ignored for the purposes of "outside". Additionally, this is probably a better structure anyway so that the opening/closing logic is housed solely in the `App` component.

Then you should update your button's `onClick` function so that it toggles `showMenu` rather than just setting its value to `true`. You can do this simply with `setShowMenu(prev => !prev)`.

Here's an example:

```
const App = () => {
  const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = React.useState(false)
  const ref = React.useRef()
  useOnClickOutside(ref, () => setShowMenu(false))

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <div className="menu-section-conatainer">
        <button
          className={"menu-link"}
          onClick={() => {
            setShowMenu(prev => !prev)
          }}
          name="Toggle Menu"
        >
          {showMenu ? "Hide Menu" : "Show Menu"}
        </button>
      </div>

      <Menu showState={showMenu}>
        Menu Items
      </Menu>
    </div>
  )
}

const Menu = ({ children, showState}) => {
  return (
    <div className="menu-expanded-wrapper">
      <div className={ showState ? "menu-expanded" : "menu-collapsed" }>
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

With no changes to your `useOnClickOutside` hook.

Comment: That's a clean solution for some use cases. What about if I can't encapsulate those components?
I can't find a way to accomplish that. Using multiple states? That would be a mess.

Comment: @FelipeCandalCampos For those cases, you can change the `useOnClickOutside` hook to accept multiple refs and then the implementation is very similar, only you'd loop over the elements to check if the click target was within any of them. For this case, I felt restructuring the HTML structure made the most sense. If you want more details I think this would be best suited with a separate question (let me know if you post one).

Comment: It's ok, that's what've done but it did not felt good. Thanks for your reply!